# getting difference between list values with variable window

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> jj = [1,3,9,4,5,6,1,2,4,1,7,9,0,4,1,9]
>>> np.diff(jj) 
[ 2  6 -5  1  1 -5  1  2 -3  6  2 -9  4 -3  8]
```

np.diff gives difference between the consecutive numbers. I am looking for difference between every element with a gap of 3 values

input: [**1**,3,9,**4**,5,6,**1**,2,4,**1**,7,9,**0**,4,1,**9**]

difference between the bold values
output : [3,-3,0,-1,-9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can use `slicing` with `step : 3`. then use [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). *You can read [understanding-slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)*

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,9,4,5,6,1,2,4,1,7,9,0,4,1,9])
b = np.diff(a[::3])
print(b)
```

Output: `array([ 3, -3,  0, -1,  9])`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most straightforward way is to slice for every third number:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,3,9,4,5,6,1,2,4,1,7,9,0,4,1,9])
>>> np.diff(arr[::3])
array([ 3, -3,  0, -1,  9])
```

Note, if you use a `numpy.ndarray` then this is fairly space-efficient since `arr[::3]` creates a *view*

Answer (score 1):

You still can use `np.diff` just pass not the whole array but a specific array like this:

```
np.diff(jj[::3])
```